# SET: not found NODE JS

Tags: node.js, nodes, development-environment, production, nodemon

I use SET NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION& nodemon server.js in my package.json file.

But the environment not change and still run in the development mode.

It also throw error like sh: 1: SET: not found in terminal.

Comment: What `shell` and `os` are you using?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You can use `cross-env` npm package to set env cross `os`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using `sh` and `terminal`, I'm guessing you're on either Mac or Linux, as most production servers are UNIX based. The correct command would be just `NODE_ENV=PRODUCTION`

Answer (score 0):

Set works only windows OS. If you used Unix like Operating systems you should just make `NODE_ENV=production`